# Review: Built-In Functions in codecademy

Tags: python

this is from codecademy, about Review: Built-In Functions:

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    return n
    if type(n) == int or type(n) == float:
        print "The absolute value of the input is ", abs(n)
    else:
        print "Not an integer or float!"
```

the error code is:
Oops, try again! Your function seems to fail on -10 when it returned -10 instead of 10.

I wonder, how the number 10 comes out? and what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

You are simply returning the argument, so it doesn't return the absolute value.  So if you give it -10 as an argument, it spits out -10, when the answer should be 10.  To resolve this, you need to return the absolute value of the argument by:

```
return abs(n)
```

You also should move the return statement to the end of the `if` part so that you don't try to return the absolute value of a non-number.

```
def distance_from_zero(n):

    if type(n) == int or type(n) == float:
        print "The absolute value of the input is ", abs(n)
        return abs(n)
    else:
        print "Not an integer or float!"
```

Answer (score 1):

When a function returns something, it immediately breaks. So all your function is doing is returning the number you pass to it.

You'll want to `return abs(n)` after your print statement.

Also, to check for type, you should use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance). To use it here, you can do:

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    if isinstance(n, (int, float)):
        n = abs(n)
        print "The absolute value of the input is ", n
        return n
    else:
        print "Not an integer or float!"
```

---

Just remember that the way Codecademy checks code is a bit "dodgy". There's an in-built forum system on Codecademy which you can check out about certain exercises. To pass the exercise, you might need to use `type()` instead of `isinstance()`, as you have done.

Comment: Great answer on the first half, but as for `isinstance`, I think the question specifically asks you to check that the type _is_ `int` or `float`, so he had that part right.

Comment: @abarnert I've added a little note at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    if type(n) == int or type(n) == float: 
        return abs(n)
    else:
        return "Nope"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def distance_from_zero(n):

    if type(n) == int or type(n) == float:
        print "The absolute value of the input is ", abs(n)
        return abs(n)
    else:
        return "Nope"
```